# Parsing floating point numbers with Parsec of Haskell

Tags: haskell, parsec

There is some code used to run parsing over calculator inputs (both integer and floating ones):

```
import Text.Parsec hiding(digit)
import Data.Functor

type Parser a = Parsec String () a

digit :: Parser Char
digit = oneOf ['0'..'9']

fp_char :: Parser Char
fp_char = oneOf ['.', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

number :: Parser Integer 
number = read <$> many1 digit

fp_number :: Parser Double
fp_number = read <$> many1 fp_char

addition :: Parser Integer
addition = do
    lhv <- number
    spaces
    char '+'
    spaces
    rhv <- number
    return $ lhv + rhv

fp_addition :: Parser Double
fp_addition = do
    lhv <- fp_number
    spaces
    char '+'
    spaces
    rhv <- fp_number
    return $ lhv + rhv
```

Obviously, this will throw an exception once a float number input which preceded or followed by '.' without any digit before/after dot character respectively. How can I constrain string evaluation to prevent from execution failure?

Comment: You say "obviously", but can you explain why it doesn't parse `.5` or `3.`?

Comment: This parser serves to be a calculator-related feature, thus any sample inputs like those in your comment to be blocked strictly enough. Such inputs might be fixed to 0.5 and 3.0 rather well, but my case doesn't have to do with that solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fp_number  :: Parsec String () Double
fp_number  = read <$> parser  where 
   parser = (++) <$> number <*> (option "" $ (:) <$> char '.'  <*> number )
```

A side note, don't forget to handle negative numbers too.

```
type Parser a = Parsec String () a

digit :: Parser Char
digit = -- same 

number :: Parser String 
number =  many1 digit

fp_number  :: Parser  Double
fp_number  = read <$> parser  where 
   parser = (++) <$> number <*> (option "" $ (:) <$> char '.'  <*> number )

fp_addition :: Parser Double
fp_addition = --same

test = parseTest fp_addition "2.123 + 213.12"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, indeed. But I get this error when compiling a module: `Couldn't match expected type Char' with actual type ParsecT String () Data.Functor.Identity.Identity [Char]' `. So, how to resolve that in order to start running?

Comment: @mission_code_now I added the full working code. Maybe you can figure out the error

Comment: Following your update, it runs smoothly. Thank you a lot, indeed.